# Have the date include the place while other Reference Line fields are defined

Tags: scrlttr2

The KOMA Script guide says on page 214:

> The reference line can actually be longer than just one line. It is printed only if at least one of variables for the reference line is not empty. Only non-empty fields will be printed. To set a seemingly empty field, you can provide content for the variable that appears empty, such as `\mbox{}`. If the reference line is omitted, the description and contents of the date variable are printed in its place.

Further on page 215:

> The date is usually output as part of the reference line. **If all other elements of the reference line are empty, a date line consisting of the location and the date is printed instead.** (Emphasis mine)

I would like to combine these options. That is, I would like to have a reference line with information such as an invoice number, but I would also like the date to be printed as *location, date*; e.g. *Birmingham, 15th August 2023*

A MWE that displays the date with location as I would like it would be:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{place}{Birmingham}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipients, Inc.\\1 High Street\\London\\AB1 2CD}
\opening{Dear Sirs or Madams,}
Please acknowledge this letter.
\closing{Yours faithfully}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

In this example, instead of a reference line the date is output as *Birmingham, August 15, 2023*. (The US date format versus UK is not of concern here.)

A MWE that includes other reference line data would be:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{place}{Birmingham}
\setkomavar{invoice}{123456789}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipients, Inc.\\1 High Street\\London\\AB1 2CD}
\opening{Dear Sirs or Madams,}
Please acknowledge this letter.
\closing{Yours faithfully}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

In this MWE, the invoice no. is included in the reference line. The date is printed on the right as *August 15, 2023* under a smaller text saying *Date* as part of the reference line.

Is there a way to have the date displayed as in the first MWE but a reference line as in the second MWE (the small text saying *Date* should be omitted)?

Obviously, a quick and cheap hack is to add `\setkomavar{date}[]{Birmingham, \today}` to the preamble. Or, for the more versatile option: `\setkomavar{date}[]{\usekomavar{place}, \today}`. But is there not a more elegant option that I could select to achieve this?